# Setting data of EditText not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I am trying to set the text of an EditText via a ListView. Once the user chooses a product from the ListView, it will then go back to the activity that holds the EditText, and change the text within the EditText.

I am relatively new to Android and Java, so excuse me for being an absolute nub.

List Java:

```
        final ListView listViewCPU = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCPU);
    listViewCPU.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    String CPUList[] = {

    "Products go here", "Products go here", "Products go here", "Products go here", "Products go here", "Products go here" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CPUList);

    listViewCPU.setAdapter(adapter);

    listViewCPU.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View myView,
                int pos, long mylng) {
            String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListmenuActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(" ", CPU);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
}
```

EditText Java:
I am getting the error on "EditText4" defining "Syntax error on token "EditText4", delete this token"

```
        EditText CPU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView4);
    CPU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent CPUList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CPUList.class);
            startActivityForResult(CPUList, 0); 
        }

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String product = i.getStringExtra(" ");
        EditText CPU = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText4));
        EditText4.setText(getIntent(i).getStringExtra(""));

    });
```

Comment: I still get the error when I use "CPU" instead of "EditText4"

Comment: should call setText on the edittex instance. Oh It's already answered. Check the first solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set this way

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View myView,
            int pos, long mylng) {
        String CPU = (String) listview.getAdapter().getItem(pos);

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListmenuActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("key", CPU);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

get the value like that

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String product = i.getStringExtra("key");
    EditText CPU = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText4));
    CPU.setText(product);
```

Comment: When using this code, the error I was previously getting is now gone, but am getting the errors "Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "product", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" on "product" and the "." in-between CPU and setText

Comment: Because you are setting the value of Edit Text that's why. So you need to set the value of the reference of the Edi text (CPU), See my code of bottom.

Comment: When I set the value of the EditText like you have shown me "CPU.setText(product);" I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Should be `CPU.setText` not `EditText4` as you dont really have that defined (as long as I can see)

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText CPU = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText4));
```

You are mising a semicolon on this line :)

Comment: I think I might of deleted it by accident when I was pasting the code into the question box on here, thanks anyway :)